# Using Xamarin Essentials in Xamarin UI Test project

Tags: xamarin

I am trying to open Browser with a link inside my test method (application is launched prior to that). I installed Xamarin essentials Nuget, and per my current understanding I am not able to use this package outside xamarin project. I found some solutions (see below, using Mock object) but this does not seem to work.

var mockLaunch = new Mock();
IBrowser open = mockLaunch.Object;
open.OpenAsync("https://i389l.app.link/JFsYo6d1Y37", BrowserLaunchMode.SystemPreferred);

Does anyone have solution how to open browser (using real Android device) inside my test method? Thank you.